# Cython: segfault when using PyMem_Malloc in a class

Tags: malloc, cython

I am having a hard time with what to me seems almost a textbook `PyMem_*` implementation from the [Cython manual](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/memory_allocation.html) (I'm in an IPython shell):

```
In [2]: %%cython -f
   ...: from cpython.mem cimport PyMem_Malloc, PyMem_Realloc, PyMem_Free
   ...: from libc.string cimport memcpy
   ...: cdef class A:
   ...:     cdef unsigned char **data
   ...:     def __cinit__(self):
   ...:         print('Allocating memory.')
   ...:         self.data = <unsigned char **>PyMem_Malloc(6)
   ...:         if not self.data:
   ...:             raise MemoryError()
   ...:
   ...:     cpdef void assign(self):
   ...:         cdef unsigned char a1[3]
   ...:         cdef unsigned char a2[3]
   ...:         a1 = bytearray(b'123')
   ...:         a2 = bytearray(b'abc')
   ...:         print('Assigning a1.')
   ...:         memcpy(self.data[0], a1, 3)
   ...:         print('Assigning a2.')
   ...:         memcpy(self.data[1], a2, 3)
   ...:         print(self.data[1][: 3])
   ...:
   ...:     def __dealloc__(self):
   ...:         print('Releasing memory.')
   ...:         PyMem_Free(self.data)
   ...: a = A()
   ...: a.assign()
   ...: del(a)
   ...: b = A()
   ...: b.assign()
   ...: del(b)
Allocating memory.
Assigning a1.
Assigning a2.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

What is wrong with my code? The only difference I see from the manual example is that I am using a 2D array of characters (they are not NUL terminated strings), so maybe I am doing something wrong there?

**EDIT**

The segfault happens at random points. I doubled the instantiation and deletion lines because most times this happens on the second pass. Or even if I run the same Cython cell twice in a row.

Thanks.

Comment: A char* is a pointer and is 8 bytes long, you allocate only 6 bytes it is not even enough for one pointer.

Comment: data[0] is just a random number, before you can use it you must allocate memory and save its address in data[0]

Comment: @ead Thanks, I am starting to understand better. I am creating an array of pointers, which is very different from, say `unsigned char a[2][3]` which is what I am really after because it's much more compact. I guess there is no way to emulate that with a dynamically allocated variable? Unless I store the data as a contiguous, 1D array and rely on the constant size of the elements...

Comment: You're assigning a whole bunch of pointers to data stored in local variables. These are nonsense as soon as the `assign` function ends

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to comments (thanks!) I re-engineered the code to use a 1-D array with "strides":

```
In [8]: %%cython -f
   ...: from cpython.mem cimport PyMem_Malloc, PyMem_Realloc, PyMem_Free
   ...: from libc.string cimport memcpy
   ...: cdef class A:
   ...:     cdef:
   ...:         unsigned char *data
   ...:         size_t ct, itemsize, size
   ...:     
   ...:     def __cinit__(self, size_t ct, size_t itemsize):
   ...:         print('Allocating memory.')
   ...:         self.data = <unsigned char *>PyMem_Malloc(ct * itemsize)
   ...:         if not self.data:
   ...:             raise MemoryError()
   ...:         self.ct = ct
   ...:         self.itemsize = itemsize
   ...:         self.size = self.ct * self.itemsize
   ...:     
   ...:     cpdef void assign(self):
   ...:         cdef unsigned char a1[3]
   ...:         cdef unsigned char a2[3]
   ...:         a1 = bytearray(b'123')
   ...:         a2 = bytearray(b'abc')
   ...:         print('Assigning a1.')
   ...:         memcpy(self.data, a1, self.itemsize)
   ...:         print('Assigning a2.')
   ...:         memcpy(self.data + self.itemsize, a2, self.itemsize)
   ...:         print(self.data[: self.itemsize])
   ...:         print(self.data[self.itemsize: self.itemsize * 2])
   ...:     
   ...:     def __dealloc__(self):
   ...:         print('Releasing memory.')
   ...:         PyMem_Free(self.data)
   ...: a = A(2, 3)
   ...: a.assign()
   ...: del(a)
Allocating memory.
Assigning a1.
Assigning a2.
b'123'
b'abc'
Releasing memory.
```

This works as expected.